# Unable to retrieve X-Forwarded-For in Tomcat 8.0 access log

Tags: tomcat

I am injecting a header with a rewrite policy on my LB to pass X-Forwarded-For header. Have verified that this appears on all the pages in the RESPONSE Header.

I have the following config in server.xml , yet i am not able to see the Remote IP/X-Forwarded-For either using %a or %h (I see Loadbalancer IP)

What could be the issue?

```
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
              internalProxies="10\.202\.13\.198"
              remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For"
              proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
              requestAttributesEnabled="true"
            />
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
              directory="logs"
              prefix="localhost_access_log"
              suffix=".txt"
              pattern="%t %a %h %{Referer}i %l %S %{User-Agent}i %U %s %r %q %A %v %p %b %I %D"
              requestAttributeEnabled="true"
              resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Log ::

[11/May/2016:11:29:39 -0700] 10.202.13.198 10.202.13.198 https:///index.action - 04B3ADCF82A212C6ECD9679BF260732D Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Safari/537.36 /rest/mywork/latest/status/notification/count 200 GET /rest/mywork/latest/status/notification/count HTTP/1.1  10.202.10.17  443 72 http-nio-8443-exec-17 13

As you see : both %a and % h are : 10.202.13.198 10.202.13.198 (my LB IP)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the REQUEST headers are being inspected. After injecting X-Forwarded-For in the request header both %a and %h shows my remote address. Also, to note X-Forwarded-For is not case sensitive.